# Reform/Liberal Burials

Tags: halacha, funeral-burial-levaya, cemetery-grave, orthodox, reform-judaism

Is there a problem with the way Progressive Judaism carry out their burials according to Orthodox Jewry?

Comment: Can you include details about what happens at those burials and what issues you think may be problematic?

Comment: I cannot as i haven't attended one but I'd like to know what the Halacha is in case a day comes that I face the decision of going or not.

Comment: In that case your best bet will be speaking with your personal rabbi for a situation specific ruling

Comment: That is always the case but I was wondering whether there's a tshuva on this or if anyone has experience in such a scenario

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52559/can-an-orthodox-jew-go-to-a-reform-burial